Method overloading: trap known arguments with fallback for unknown arguments
I have a legacy project that has a base class which represents complex objects that are built at runtime. These objects have a state with getter/setter methods for the state properties.
In some cases, the state properties are well known, in which case I would like to enforce strict type checking. However, I need a fallback when using state properties which are unknown.
Here's a basic idea of what this looks like in practice:
interface KnownProps {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

class Foo {
    private state:Record<string, unknown> = {};

    set<P extends keyof KnownProps>(key: P, value:KnownProps[P]): void;
    set(key:string, value:unknown):void;
    set(key:string, value:unknown):void {
        this.state[key] = value;
    }

    get<P extends keyof KnownProps>(key:P):KnownProps[P];
    get(key:string):unknown;
    get(key:string):unknown {
        return this.state[key];
    }
}

const foo = new Foo();

// Overloads match as desired:
foo.set("name", "Steve"); // key: "name", value:string
foo.set("age", 37); // key: "age", value: number
foo.set("birthday", new Date()); // key: "birthday", value: unknown

const name = foo.get("name"); // string
const age = foo.get("age"); // number
const birthday = foo.get("birthday"); // unknown;

The problem is that TypeScript is very generous in trying to match an overload (as it ought to be), so if I pass in a known property with an invalid type, I don't get any error reporting:
// Should throw errors
foo.set("name", 37); // expected a string
foo.set("age", "Steve"); // expected a number

I thought that using a conditional type might "trap" the known property and throw an error:
{
    set<P extends keyof KnownProps, V>(key: P, value:V extends KnownProps[P] ? KnownProps[P] : never): void;
}

But, alas, TypeScript still generously accepts the incorrect type definition via the "fallback" overload.

Use conditional types on the "key", not the value. As of TypeScript 5.0, make sure to use a const modifier on the type parameter so that it will match the literal property name rather than widen the type to string:
{
    set<const P>(key: P, value:P extends keyof KnownProps ? KnownProps[P] : unknown): void;
    set(key:string, value:unknown):void {
        this.state[key] = value;
    }
}

You should now get the errors you were expecting:
// Overloads match as desired:
foo.set("name", "Steve"); // key: "name", value:string
foo.set("age", 37); // key: "age", value: number
foo.set("birthday", new Date()); // key: "birthday", value: unknown

const name = foo.get("name"); // string
const age = foo.get("age"); // number
const birthday = foo.get("birthday"); // unknown;

// Known properties now apply strict type checking:
foo.set("name", 37);
//              ~~
//              Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
foo.set("age", "Steve");
//             ~~~~~~~
//             Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.

Prior to TypeScript 5.0, you'd follow the advice above, but you'd have to remember to use as const when calling set() to get the same behavior:
/////////////////////////
// BEFORE TYPESCRIPT 5.0:

{
    set<P>(key: P, value:P extends keyof KnownProps ? KnownProps[P] : unknown): void;
    set(key:string, value:unknown):void {
        this.state[key] = value;
    }
}

foo.set("name" as const, 37);
//                       ~~
//                       Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
foo.set("age" as const, "Steve");
//                      ~~~~~~~
//                      Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.


